# How can I hide extra component span tags in Tapestry?

Tags: java, tapestry

If I use a span tag to render a component like <span jwcid="@If" .../>, my HTML ends up with a bunch of useless span tags. Most of the time, that's ok, but in some cases, it's interfering with my CSS or making the page invalid.  Is there a way to tell Tapestry to process the tag, but not actually render it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `org.apache.tapestry.renderTags` [Tapestry configuration property](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/usersguide/configuration.html#Configuration%20Properties):

> Specifies whether or not some block level components will render their 
>   template tag names by default.
>
> This currently affects the If, Else and For components.

You can also specify the `renderTag` parameter for a particular component instance, see the [If component](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/components/general/if.html) documentation.

Comment: Took me a while to get around to testing this but renderTag="false" did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You should be aware that changing this property in the configuration breaks some built-in Tapestry components (such as the default exception page) in all versions where the property exists up to 4.1.5. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAPESTRY-1431